# Explicit solution to this equation

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

Simple problem: The equation below has two solutions for $x$ for a range of parameter values (see below). This is straightforward to see graphically. I need to find both of these solutions. Some additional information:

- Approximations are OK if necessary
- Ideally both solutions will be found, but ideas for finding either individually are also helpful
- In the equation below: $k \approx 0.1$, $n \approx 2.5$

The equation:

$\frac{1}{n} e^{-n(1-e^{-x/n})}e^{\frac{x}{n}} = 1-e^{ (x/n^2)(1-e^{-x/n})^{-1}e^{\frac{x}{n}}k}$

Comment: If approximations are OK, why don't you use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method?

Comment: Thanks for the response, @AndreiRykhalski. Solving numerically isn't the issue, though---I need the solution in terms of $k$ and $n$. I don't think I see hwo the bisection method could help with that.